# Using the service.check_command variable in Icinga2 action_url query string

Tags: icinga, icinga2, grafana

I'm trying to make an `action_url` which will dynamically link from IcingaWeb2 to Grafana graphs. I have it working up to a point, but I'd like to add another variable...the `$SERVICECHECKCOMMAND$` `service.check_command` variable, and it's not working...I assume I need to set that environment variable somewhere?

I'd like this to work:

> action_url =
>   "http://grafana-server.example/grafana/dashboard/db/generic-check?var-device=$HOSTNAME$&var-check=$SERVICEDESC$&var-checkmetric=$SERVICECHECKCOMMAND$&var-datatype=perfdata&var-value=value"

`$HOSTNAME$` and `$SERVICEDESC$` are working.

I've added environment variables to the default template before, but that was for mail host/service notifications, I'm having no luck getting it to work for `action_url`.

Anyone familiar with where I can set something like:

```
env = {
    "SERVICECHECKCOMMAND" = "$service.check_command$",
    "SERVICEDESC" = "$service.name$",
    "HOSTNAME" = "$host.name$",
    "SERVICEDISPLAYNAME" = "$service.display_name$",
  }
```

for `action_url`s? Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really use macros for that, because *_url is a configuration field.

The web interfaces try to do some expansion, but can't handle everything.

I'd recommend something like this in `apply Service`:

```
action_url = "http://" + host.name + "/test.cgi?check=" + check_command
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That did it, very helpful. And forced me to get using apply rules, which I need to start using. Thanks.